# Issues parsing json from imgut

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to parse and decode data coming from IMGUR website. However when I try to print out one of the properties from Data  it doesn’t show [anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZlyY.png). How do I fix this? Also I want to access the contents of images, specifically the links. How can I access the contents Of the image since it’s an array?

```
struct PhotoResponse:Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let status: Int
    let data: [Data]
}

struct Data:Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let views: Int
    let link: String
    let images: [Image]?
    let animated: Bool?
}


struct Image: Codable {
    let id: String
    let imageDescription: String?
    let link: String?
    let size: Int
}
class NetworkService{
    static let shared = NetworkService()
    private let baseURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery"
    private init() {}
    
    
    func getJSON( searchName: String, completion: @escaping([Data]) -> Void){
        let endPoints = baseURL + "/search/time/week/?q=\(searchName)"
        guard let url = URL(string: endPoints ) else{
            return
        }
        var request =  URLRequest(url: url)
        let headers = ["Authorization": ""]
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to query database", error)
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data not received\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do{
                let decodedJson = try decoder.decode(PhotoResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(decodedJson.data)
                }

            }catch let error{
                print("Json failed to decode\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
 
}

NetworkService.shared.getJSON(searchName: "cat") {  (photos) in
            for photo in photos {
                print(photo.title)
                print(photo.id)
            }
```

Comment: It says your `photos` array has 60 values. Verify your returned json matches your struct.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hello I have verified but for some reason it's not reflecting when I try to access a property –

Comment: Swift already has a `Data` struct, try renaming yours to something else, like `MyData`.

Comment: similarly for `Image`.

Comment: turned my comment into an answer (before someone plagiarise it).

Comment: Could you share a sample of the json returned?

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix it. @JoakimDanielson can you please look at my other question? I'm trying to cace images

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Swift already has a `Data` struct, try renaming yours to something else, like `MyData`. Do the same with `Image`.

Comment: If this was the correct answer then OP would get a compile time error, right? Also look at the screenshot, the debugger says the type is Image_Browser.Data and not Data (or Foundation.Data).